# Automatic format all files in Springs tool suite

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How to format all file in Springs Tools suite? like ctrl+Shift+f, but all files in our project.
Is STS have setting? like before compile, all files will be formatted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple files and execute "format" on them (don't need to open them). In addition to that you can enable the cleanup actions so that every file gets formatted on every save action.

Comment: Thanks it work.. :D . but it doesn't  in *.zul file .  it must be opened first.